# Angular $scope losing child data in certain situation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having an issue where, when I simply `console.log($scope.visitors)` my data is fine, but when I `console.log($scope.visitors)` and then try to open a AngularUI Bootstrap dialog, the `$scope.visitors.optionalFields` object is empty.

Now, I've spent some time trying to replicate the issue in jsbin and I wasn't able to get it to happen, so it may be difficult to answer; just hoping somebody might have an idea what could be causing it.

So I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.visitors = [
    {
        company:"one",
        optionalFields: {
            passportNumber:"ppt",
            contactNumber:"tel",
            licensePlate:"1234"
        },
        firstName:"some",
        lastName:"guy",
    }
]
```

I `ng-repeat` through these with `visitor in visitors` and each one has a button with `ng-click="editVisitorDialog(visitor)"`

Now, if I make editVisitorDialog like this:

```
$scope.editVisitorDialog = function (visitor) {
    console.log($scope.visitors);
    console.log(visitor);
}
```

Then both `$scope.visitors` and `visitor` look good, they have all of their properties.

However, if I simply add to this function (i.e., the log calls are still at the top of the function), each visitor in `$scope.visitors` will have an empty `optionalFields` object.

```
$scope.editVisitorDialog = function (visitor) {
    console.log($scope.visitors); // missing the optionalFields items
    console.log(visitor); // missing the optionalFields items

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'app/checkin/edit_visitor/edit_visitor.html',
        controller: EditVisitorController,
        resolve: {
            visitor: function () {
                return visitor;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }, function () {
    });
}
```

Comment: Set up a $watch on your $scope.visitors object using true for `objectEquality` and  you may be able to find out what piece of code is modifying the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `console.log()` with an object it doesn't really log the object. It's rather like an inspection tool where you can see the **current** state, not the state at the time `console.log()` was called.

Try `console.log(visitor.optionalFields.passportNumber)` instead and I guarantee that it will log "ppt" (in your example).

That in turn means that somehwere in the added code the optional fields get lost.

Comment: This led me to the problem.  I was resetting some fields in the modal dialog, but since the modal isn't actually a new window, just the look and feel of a new window, it was inheriting scope from the parent controller, and hence I was resetting the values in the parent.